# Is there a problem with the compatibilaty of my chipset?

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, acpi

I've recently built my own PC and i want to run Ubuntu on it.
however when i try to boot ubuntu from my usb drive it says:

> ACPI PCC probe failed

I tried installing with `nomodeset` and the install worked however after the reboot it would no longer work. It would just boot to a purple screen and freeze

I think this is a problem with my graphics card as the install works when using the integrated graphics provided with my  processor

I have been having this problem for a couple of days and none of the solutions on the forums seem to work.

i did try changing the `/etc/default/grub` file in recovery mode but that didn't seem to work.

Should i try something other than `nemodeset`?
Is it a problem with nouveau?
should i blacklist nouveau while keeping nomodeset as a "boot parameter"

All help is greatly appreciated

im using a Gigabyte Nvidia GeForce GTX 960

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install a driver for your GTX 960.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
```

and reboot without nomodeset.

Comment: I tried that and the install seemed to have worked but it still boots to the purple screen.

do i need to blacklist nouveau or is there something i've done wrong

Thanks for your help

Comment: No, you do not have to blacklist nouveau. But it seems that you did something wrong already. It is hard to guess what.

Comment: Is there any more information i can give you that would help solve my problem?

if it helps at all. I think i can boot into ubuntu with my integrated graphics. is there anything i could do there??

Comment: Please edit your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: Is there any way i can send an image of my monitor screen or do i have to type it all out?

Comment: Can you select text and copy it? Then you can paste it. If you can't then you can upload the image somewhere and provide a link.

Comment: Is there any way i could email you the photo as i am on a different device than my computer that im trying to fix

Comment: http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-3035-19.html

Comment: Thanks for all you help. the problem is resolved. i just deactivated my integrated graphics

Thanks again.